# Minimising & Maximising Java fx app programmatically

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am creating a custom TitleBar for my application, and i am implementing the *Minimise* && *Maximise* && *Close* buttons for my `Stage`.. I am achieving that by using the `TRANSPARENT` `StageStyle`

i Maximise this way

```
Stage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight()-Margins);
Stage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() -Margins);
Stage.setX(1.0);
Stage.setY(0.0);
// let others know about it
```

I Close this way

```
// stop all custom stuffs
Stage.close();
```

&& I want to Minimise *any way to achieve that??*

Minimisation is my problem.. Incase of what i have tried, i have tried `hide()`, `toBack()` -(*which seems to persuade you if you have piles of windows on screen*) and they all do not work

Comment: why are you actually trying to re-invent the wheel? Is there some greater goal to it?

Comment: You may be interested in the third party [undecorator project](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator), which appears to provide what you are trying to implement (fully customized title bar for an application which does not rely on an OS window provided title bar).

Comment: @specializt yes Sir, i got to meet some UI requirements, and also the way the app is being built the default will not do it.

Comment: @jewelsea i will check that Sir, thnks

Comment: If you explain in your question the UI requirements you need to meet and why the default OS window manager does not meet them (by editing your question), it is easier for people to provide relevant answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Maximize and de-maximize a JavaFX stage**

Use [`stage.setMaximized(boolean value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaximized-boolean-).

To maximize:

```
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

To restore to the pre-maximized size:

```
stage.setMaximized(false);
```

---

*Update for further questions*

> i want a java way of hiding effect of my app without closing and reopen on demand

Sounds like your question really about how to reduce the application to an icon or restore it from an icon.

**Iconify and de-iconify a JavaFX stage**

To [iconify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setIconified-boolean-):

```
stage.setIconified(true);
```

To deiconify:

```
stage.setIconified(false);
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for the easy approach to the maximisation, pretty straight forward back & forth, i will vote up for that, but, my problem is the minimisation not the de-maximisation to be precise, if i make sense.. i want a java way of hiding effect of my app without closing and reopen on demand, how can i do that sir?

Comment: Updated answer to address additional question.

Comment: Sir, Jewelsea Thank you, it works!!!. and also for the easy appraoch.. sorry for the wait, i was on mobile by then. quick question sir, if you do not mind, "are you on the java fx team??"